# Where am I going wrong in measuring the average voltage across my load?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, transformer

I have set up the circuit below and now need to measure the amplitude and the average voltage across the load (10k ohms).

[image]

Oscilloscope readings:

[image]

The top curve is the input waveform, or the point between the diode and the load. The middle curve is the bottom curve minus the top curve, i.e. channel 2 - channel 1. The bottom curve is the output waveform, or the point between the load and the transformer.

The transformer I am currently using:

[image]

The input and output waveforms for the circuit with the diode REMOVED:

[image]

Note that Ampl(1) refers to the top curve and Ampl(2) refers to the bottom one.

If one correctly, the measured values should satisfy the relation

$$V_{av}=\frac{V_0}{\pi}$$

However, my values were $$V_0=230 V$$ and

$$V_{av} = 119 V$$

Clearly, there is something wrong here. I used a Keysight DSOX1102G Digital Storage Oscilloscope to get these measured values. I thought it might be a problem with the diode, but I swapped it out for a fresh one and there was no change. I then tried measuring the voltage across the load with a digital multimeter, but this gave a reading of 12.7 volts. I'm not sure how to interpret this value. Is this the average voltage across the load? And why is it so far away from the measured values of the oscilloscope?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65333/discussion-on-question-by-whatwhatwhat-where-am-i-going-wrong-in-measuring-the-a).

Comment: To check your result, you can use a classical needle voltmeter: because of the mechanism inertia, it will naturally integrate the waveform and get you what you want.

Comment: Your description of where you made those 'scope measurements doesn't make sense - a voltage measurement is *between 2 points*, not at a point. Where were the ground clips of your probes when making these measurements?

Answer (score 3):

The most obvious problem is your first equation, $$V_{av}=\frac{V_0}{\pi}$$ This is correct for a half-wave rectified circuit. You, on the other hand, are clearly using a full-wave rectifier, as evidenced by trace 1 on your scope display, and for this situation $$V_{av}=\frac{2V_0}{\pi}$$ To make matters worse, you are not computing the average of the rectified output. Instead you are combining the two traces, and this accounts for the fact that the second peak on trace 1 is about 40 volts higher than the first.

So. Trace 2 is apparently the raw transformer output. It is about 40 V pk-pk, which corresponds to about a 14 VRMS transformer winding.

Trace 1 is your rectified load current. It should be about 20 volts pk-pk, but since you are using a 1:1 scope probe while the scope thinks its a 10:1, you are getting about 200 volts as a reading. So 231 is not unreasonable.

If your scope were computing only trace 1, you'd get a nominal 147 volt average, rather than 120. Two things are affecting this. First, the output is not a very good sine. Second, the modulation caused by the subtraction of trace 2 is messing things up.

Comment: Are there 2 different kinds of diodes for half-rectification and full-rectification? My book mentioned to use a 1N4001 diode, and this is what I'm using, but it continued on assuming that this diode will create a half-rectified waveform.

Comment: Look, whatwhatwhat, your scope trace is that of a full-wave rectifier. Please Google. It is not produced by a single diode. So, somewhere you've gotten confused.

Comment: Half wave vs. full wave rectification has nothing to do with the diodes you use, it has to do with how you have them configured. A simple google search for "half wave vs full wave rectification" will give you hundreds of excellent hits.